# Word VBA- ComboBox text reset text output

Tags: vba, ms-word, combobox, ms-office, userform

I'm having trouble with combo box's specifically when a user clicks one of the options in the dropdown menu the text is entered into the document but if they made an error and select another option in the combo box it inputs the the text from both times (the error and right answer). How can I set it up so it will get rid of the text from the error.

The code is below:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

With ComboBox1

.AddItem "F1"

.AddItem "G2"

.AddItem "R3"

.AddItem "G4"

End With



End Sub



Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()

Dim ComboBox1 As Range

Set ComboBox1 = Doc1.Bookmarks("bmc1").Range

ComboBox1.Text = Me.ComboBox1.Value

Set ComboBox1 = Doc2.Bookmarks("bmc1").Range

ComboBox1.Text = Me.ComboBox1.Value

End Sub
```

Comment: Your problem stems from poor solution design. I would never use a control's change event to commit changes to a document. Doing so does not allow the user to cancel out of the form without making changes. It is much better to only commit changes to a document when the user clicks OK/Apply/Finish or whatever.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you are creating a new instance of the bookmark `bmc1` every time you call the `Change()` function, and so a new bookmark is created, and this is where the new text is inserted.

Make the bookmark into a `Public` variable, and initialize it in the `Initialize()` function.

```
Public CBR As Range

Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
  CBR.Text = Me.ComboBox1.Value
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
  Set CBR = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("bmc1").Range
  With ComboBox1
    .AddItem "F1"
    .AddItem "G2"
    .AddItem "R3"
    .AddItem "G4"
  End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Err, no, that won't solve the problem. The code in the question clearly shows that there are two documents with identically named bookmarks. The question, although poorly worded, also indicates that they are in front of the text instead of enclosing it. That is why each time the text is changed the new text is inserted in front of the existing text instead of replacing it.

Comment: @TimothyRylatt; when I tried OP's code (although I did ignore the second document as it does the same thing), the bookmark reads say F1, and then G2F1, because it is a new bookmark. With my code, which is what I think the OP is asking, the bookmark reads F1 and then just G2.

Comment: To gain a better understanding of how bookmarked ranges work see https://wordmvp.com/FAQs/MacrosVBA/InsertingTextAtBookmark.htm